# rad to deg using method Java

Tags: java

I have a simple calculator program

```
package assignment.pkg10;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment10 {

public double rad2Degree  (double deg, double rad)
{
   rad = 0;
   deg =  rad*180  / Math.PI;
   return deg;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

  Assignment10 as10 = new Assignment10();


    System.out.println("Select which function you want to use:");
    System.out.println(" S - sine\n C - cosine\n T - tangent\n "+ 
            "R - square root\n N - natural log\n X - exit program");
    String plugIn = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    char op = plugIn.charAt(0);
    String sValue = plugIn.substring(2);
    double num = Double.parseDouble(sValue);

    while (!"X".equals(plugIn))
    {
      switch (op)
      {
       case 'S' : 
        op = 's';
        double sine = Math.sin(num);
          as10.rad2Degree(0, 0);
        System.out.println("sin = " + sine + "\n degrees: " + as10.rad2Degree(0, 0));
        break;

    case 'C' : 
        op = 'c';
        double cosine = Math.cos(num);
        System.out.println("cos = " + cosine);
        break;

    case 'T' : 
        op = 't';
        double tangent = Math.tan(num);
        System.out.println("tan = " + tangent);
        break;

    case 'R' : 
        op = 'r';
        double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(num);
        System.out.println("the square root = " + squareRoot);
        break;

    case 'N' : 
        op = 'n';
        double naturalLog = Math.log(num);
        System.out.println("ln = " + naturalLog);
        break;

}

System.out.println("S - sine\n C - cosine\n T - tangent\n "+ 
            "R - square root\n N - natural log\n X - exit program");
            plugIn = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
}

System.out.println("Goodbye ");

}

}
```

I can't seem to figure out what to put into the method **rad2Degree** to convert Radians to Degrees so I can output the radians and degrees.

An example of the output would be :

```
Select which function you want to use:
 S - sine
 C - cosine
 T - tangent
 R - square root
 N - natural log
 X - exit program
s 4
sin = -0.7568024953079282
 degrees: .069756473
```

Comment: Why is the first statement `rad = 0;`? Anything `* 0` is `0`.

Comment: I was testing out what it would output @ElliottFrisch

Comment: There is no reason why your **rad2Degree** method should accept more than one argument (why do you need the degrees if that is what you are computing?).  Other than the problem that @ElliottFrisch mentioned, I see nothing wrong with that method; you are using the correct conversion.

Comment: You are passing 0 to rad2Degree in the 'S' case block; change this to num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really should only need to take 1 number. youre version was very close, but try something more like this:

```
public double rad2Degree  (double rad)
{
   double deg =  rad*180  / Math.PI;
   return deg;
}
```

Comment: my out put comes out as: Select which function you want to use:
 
sin = -0.7568024953079282
                                              degrees: 0.0

Comment: just figured it out ...thank you very much @WilliamB.